# Is there any way to use method Validate of apiController?

Tags: c#, class, annotations

I wish to use this method in my API, but it's invalid.

[Error when I've tried to use this.Validate();](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BPtB.png)

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.validate?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: You need to add an example of what you tried and the error you get.

Comment: I've updated my question to add image error.

Comment: First of all, please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question, so that others can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inheriting `ApiController` class to your controller, then you can call it using `this` operator

For example,

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
...
public class SampleController : ApiController
{

   public IActionResult GetSample()
   {
       //Your code goes here
       this.Validate();  //This is the way to call Validate method
   }
}
```

Comment: @ChengchheavSong, did it answer your question? any feedback?

Comment: First, thank you for answer.
I've tried your sample above and got the error as image.
Do I miss something?

Comment: Error image in the question.

Comment: Please research for new error, There are lot of similar Q&A are available over internet. Your new error is not relevant to this question. **Hint**: *You just need to import correct namespace where `IActionResult` is defined*. MSDN documentation (.net core) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Your example is work now, but we need to use dll System.Web.Http version 5.2.3 or later.
Can you edit your example to add this note?